# When can we exchange sum limit and integral

Tags: integration

A simple question: when can wo exchange sum and integral?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int f_n(x)dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)dx=\int f(x)dx$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n(x)dx=\int\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)dx=\int f(x)dx$$

Comment: If the sequence of function{fn} is converges uniformly to f the we can exchange..

Comment: Since the other posters hit the big condition, I'll add: in the context of Riemann integration, there is a weakened version of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/dominated.pdf. Further, while this is not theoretically that useful in my experience, pointwise convergence is sufficient if it is known that the limit function is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

**Exchange sum and integral:** For Riemann's integral, it is necessary that the serie $\sum f_n$ converge uniformly. For Lebesgue's integral, it suffices that each function $f_n$ is positive.